Determine whether "all records" were selected or "no records" using ArcPy
I'm developing a tool where a SelectLayerByAttribute is performed, and the selected rows are deleted.
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(my_layer, "NEW_SELECTION", my_sql)
print(arcpy.GetCount_management(my_layer))

The problem is, the resulting count seems to be the same whether all the records were selected, or none of them. Is there a programmatic way to make this distinction?

Use getSelectionSet method. Fastest of all
